# ajax detect if a page has been altered

Tags: jquery, ajax

Right now, I'm using this code to load a numerical value from a page:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mypage.php",
  cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
  $("#results").append(html);
});
```

However, if the results are different I would like to have an alert pop up then fade out. How should I do this?

Bonus question: how can I get this to run continuously?

Comment: Somehow I don't think I'll be getting any bonus points if I answer your "bonus question". Try putting it into a new question, or better yet, search SO for it.

Comment: "However, if the results are different" What do you mean by "different"?

Comment: Different than what? The last result? You'd need to store it in a variable somewhere.

Comment: @crush Sorry. Say it pulls the data the first time and the result is "4", but then it runs it again and the result is now "5". (The server is automatically updating this output)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've given, this is the best I can come up with. See the comment about where to put your alert. You provided no code for it, so I'll assume you can handle that on your own.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "mypage.php",
  cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
  var results = $("#results");

  if (results.html() == html) {
      //results are the same...do nothing...
  } else {
      //results are different if they aren't equal...
      $("#results").append(html);

      //popup your alert here...
  }
});
```

You could of course eliminate the else block by checking `!=` instead of `==` but I figured you might decide you want to do something if they are equal.